# How do I unhighlight an already saved PDF in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: pdf

I'm searching for a free way of unhighlighting (and removing the colors in the background) an already saved PDF and, which, since it is already saved, I'm not able to just undo it.

I searched for a lot of PDF editing Ubuntu software but found nothing with which I could achieve that.

I ended up installing EaseUS PDF Editor, which did the trick, as you can see in the photos, but I'm so, so not in the mood to pay 29,47 € just to do that.

[image: unhighlighted PDF]

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript can do this.

You can call it as `gs` with a bunch of options, but it's easiest (IMHO) to call it as `ps2pdf`, which, despite its name, allows the input to be a pdf as well. The `-dShowAnnots=false` option will remove the annotations/highlights.

```
ps2pdf -dShowAnnots=false "input.pdf" "output.pdf"
```

Comment: *********@******:~/Downloads$ ps2pdf -dShowAnnots=false "2022-04.pdf" "2022-05.pdf"
It returned the exact same document

Comment: I was assuming the "highlight" was a PDF annotation. If it's actually part of the body of the document, then this won't work. You could try importing the PDF into inkscape and removing that element, but that's not nearly as simple.

Answer (score 0):

From the comment of frabjous

I use GIMP to do it within 2 minutes.

Open GIMP and the PDF on it.

Go to Menu bar `Colors` > `Map` > `Color Exchange...`

[image: Color-exchange-window]

Use color picker and select the background color which you want to erase, and select the color of sheet.

Set threshold as much as it allows; press `ok`

[image: result]

I still feel weird of bold text on the section, but it was not asked.

Comment: This will both rasterize the pdf and obscure the text behind the watermark. I doubt that's desired.

Comment: @frabjous, just a proof of your 'not nearly as simple' point. PDF is lame. It is a best conspiracy to disable Unix/Linux users from searching easily.